# Keming in 'Careers' PDF résumé

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I just applied to a job on [Careers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/jobs/info), and while reviewing the PDF résumé that was sent to them, I noticed some bad rendering or perhaps [kerning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kerning#Noun) going on:

Stack Overflow Careers HTML site:

[image: Beautiful]

PDF résumé:

[image: Oh the huge manatees]

You can see the problem in between "CSS" and "as", and again between "CoffeeScript" and "and".  It might have something to do with the bold/emphasis tags too.

I am running on [OS X v10.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion) and am viewing in Preview.

Comment: @Oded Must...resist...correcting...

Comment: Oh I so got title trolled...

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](http://shaktronics.com/files/2012/03/kerning.png)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! Looks like there actually is a blank between "**CoffeeScript**" and "and", it's just extremely slim. We'll have to jazz up our PDF rendering engine a bit to give 'em the space they deserve...

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help.

Comment: Thank you @RobbyCornelissen for preserving the pun in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should look better now, please try again!

Comment: Good Job, looks great.
http://i.imgur.com/guoze.gif